# Constructing intersections in a regular polygon

Tags: geometry, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

Consider a regular polygon with $n$ vertices. The position of the vertices are given by $e^{2 i \pi k / n}$ for $k \in \{1 \ldots n\}$. The vertices are in $\mathbb{R}[i]$ but they are also in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle \Phi_n(x) \rangle$ where $\Phi_n$ is the nth cyclotomic polynomial.

In this field, the vertices can be represented as $1, x, \ldots, x^{n-1}$.

Consider the lines going through, respectively, $x^a$ and $x^b$ and $x^c$ and $x^d$, and let them intersect at point $u$.

1. Does $u \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle \Phi_n(x) \rangle$? If not, what field extension do we need?
2. How would one go about computing $u$?

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates, $e^{2\pi ik/n}$ is $(\cos(2\pi k/n),\sin(2\pi k/n))$, so you can write down the equations of the lines between two such points, and solve for their intersection.

Comment: Yes but how do I go from that to a point in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle \Phi_n(x) \rangle$? Is it even possible?

Comment: The intersection will be some $(x,y)$ which corresponds to some complex number $x+yi$, where $x$ and $y$ will be expressions involving sines & cosines of $2\pi k/n$ for various values of $k$. Those can, in turn, be expressed in terms of the $e^{2\pi ik/n}$ numbers you started with, so you'll have them in the form you want. I think. why not try it, see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x^a, x^b)$ and $(x^c, x^d)$ be the two segments; if they intersect they do so at:

$$\frac{x^{-a}+x^{-b}-x^{-c}-x^{-d}}{x^{-a-b}-x^{-c-d}}$$